# having syntax error in my php code

Tags: php

i am having some king of error on my code if you test i get syntax error on line 7 and this is part of my code. i am trying to put php inside php code

```
<?php
$stringData = "

    <div > " .$strin. " </div>

    <?php
    $width = $_GET['width'];
    $heigh = $_GET['height'];

        echo '<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"example.com/page.php?width='.$width.'&height='.$heigh.'\"></script>';

    ?>

    ";
?>
```

my code forwards the php code that is inside another php to aanother page but i don't know how do i put it currectly inside php. i used `\"` on some places

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
<?php
$stringData = "

    <div > " .$strin. " </div>

    <?php
    $width = $_GET['width'];
    $heigh = $_GET['height'];

        echo '<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"example.com/page.php?width='.$width.'&height='.$heigh.'\"></script>';

    ?>

    ";
?>
```

and use the following:

```
$stringData = "<div > " .$strin. " </div>";
$width = $_GET['width'];
$heigh = $_GET['height'];
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="example.com/page.php?width='.$width.'&height='.$heigh.'"></script>';
```

Comment: what have edited bro ?

Comment: Your $stringData double quotes were not closed thus your <?php tag was inside the string.
This code will run. Give it a try

Comment: can you edit your answer make it inside my code dear ?

Comment: It's your question not mine. I am simply giving you the answer.
I think what you want is to modify your code. If that is so then the answer I have posted is the complete replacement of the code you have given in the question.

Comment: :D sorry i mean answer

Comment: dear, i thinnk you miss understand....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136987/discussion-between-shakti-phartiyal-and-mm-pp).